# Will `Notify_URL` override previous set IPN data

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am building an IPN extension for a website, but the service provider for the cart used at the moment has the option `Notify_URL` set (in the paypal submission form) for its own internal handling (which is somewhat flawed). If an IPN URL is set on the PayPal sellers profile, will both be used, or only one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be some confusion on this subject. Some are claiming that both will work. They claim it should notify both in this situation. Though it appears that with subscription based payments, PayPal will only use the IPN URL set in your PayPal profile.

However, on the official PayPal documentation:

> You can specify an IPN listener for a specific payment; this is the
>   only way to receive IPNs associated with Adaptive Payments. In this
>   case, PayPal sends the IPN message to the listener specified in the
>   notification URL for a specific button or API operation instead of the
>   listener specified in your Profile.

Which seems to suggest that the notify_url will override the profile settings. I would assume that it would be better to follow the PayPal documentation then something that may be working even though it isn't intended to.

Source: [PayPal Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNSetup)

It's also worth noting that if you disable IPNs in your PayPal account, neither will work.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/) may have changed since this was last answered. I was also curious what was given precedence: `notify_url` or your profile's IPN url. From the docs:

> Optionally, you can override the URL to specify another listener for specific payments.

Here the wording is slightly confusing, but it seems that even if you have IPN turned off in your profile, if you pass a `notify_url` value in with the payment, it will still be sent. Bold added by me:

> The IPN message will always be sent to your notification URL unless receiving IPN messages has been disabled. **Even though you have not enabled receiving IPN messages in your Profile or you have reset your preference by turning off IPN messages, PayPal still sends IPN messages to the notification URL you specify for a specific payment**.

I have seen this work first hand, which is why I investigated it more to make sure it was working correctly. My IPN History told me "your IPN notifications are turned off," prompting me with a link to turn it on. However, below that was a history. The reason was because I was passing in my desired `notify_url` with the transaction.

So @johnmadrak's statement, "It's also worth noting that if you disable IPNs in your PayPal account, neither will work," is actually not true. Even if you've turned the setting off in your profile, passing in a `notify_url` still works.

Comment: This is actually a problem we are having. We use Wix Store, which overrides our IPN URL by setting their own notify_url, and only Wix gets IPN notifications, but we don't.